# Registering a User Control based Form UI Control - Namespace

Tags: xsd, c1-cms

Documentation http://docs.composite.net/Console/CreatingFormControls under the title "Registering a User Control based Form UI Control" says "you must first register an XML namespace private to your organization" but doesn't explain how.

So my question is how do I create my own namespace? Am I to create an xml schema or can Composite-C1 export a namespace based on Global data type? Any help would be great. Never created an xml schema (assuming this is what is required).

I have created my asp net control and added this to my c1 console but as I try to add new new data item it produces an error:
ConfigurationErrorsException:
The configuration could not be found for name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an XML namespace by assigning a URI (in a portion of URI-space that you control) to serve as the namespace name, and then using that namespace name in appropriate ways, typically as part of the qualified name of elements, attributes, and other objects that you define.  (If this sounds vague and indeterminate, that's because it is.)

The function of namespaces (I'm speaking specifically of XML namespace here, but much of what I say applies to other things people call namespaces) is to prevent collisions between names assigned by different people.  The method is to say "You create names in your namespace, and I'll create names in my namespace, and since they are in different namespaces our names can never collide."  Of course, the namespaces are guaranteed different only if you follow the rule (almost never explicitly stated, although it's absolutely central to the whole idea) that you create namespaces only in the part of URI space that you control.  You may control part of URI space by owning a domain name, or by owning part of the tree structure of the URI paths in a domain owned by your employer, or by other means.  If you share responsibility for some part of URI space with others, you will need to coordinate with them somehow (many organizations follow a sort of "first come, first served" rule - anyone can claim a particular URI in the organization's URI space by putting something in the appropriate place on the server, and once they do, others in that organization can't claim the same URI).

So the key action in creating a namespace is the abstract one of identifying a name and dedicating it to the function of serving as a namespace name.  If you own your own domain, it's just a decision you have to make; if you share a domain, you may need to write something down somewhere so none of your colleagues accidentally claims the same URI as a namespace name.  (It is, of course, good practice to put some documentation of the namespace at the URI in question, but there is no Big Brother to check that everyone in the Web does so.)

Once you have chosen a namespace name and done whatever is needed in your organization to prevent intra-organizational conflicts over it, the document you cite tells you what you have to write where to tell that particular system's registry about the name.  Mostly it's a matter of editing some configuration files and telling them where your widgets are.  I saw no mention of any requirement for an XSD schema document (but I skimmed a lot).

Comment: Whew, thanks. Appreciate your time in explaining in full. I get the gist of what you're saying but to add a simple form in C1 console using ASP NET control appears to be well over kill. I just want a control to appear on one site and nothing else. I don't want an XML URI namespace somewhere that is only required once. Once again thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Rob we'll soften our docs here - you basically just need to come up with a unique URL or string and stick to that when you reference your stuff. Thanks for highlighting this.

Comment: Ok no problem. I've just now managed to create an empty URI reference and it worked. The main problem was I added a name property with full namespace "Controls.ABC.Test" instead of name="test"... it's working now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

OK managed to resolve the problem.

Where I thought I needed some xml namespace was incorrect. All I needed was an empty namespace reference. The error was related to the control name and not the namespace.

However my question did relate to namespace URI in general which I believe @C. M. Sperberg-McQuee answered perfectly.